# Angular 4 Bootstrap 4.0.0.alpha-6 doesn't work

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

Bootstrap dropdown doesn't work

app.module.ts

```
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
...
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
...
]
...
```

dashboard.component.html

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
        aria-expanded="false">
        Select Dashboard
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="selectDashboard('d1')">Dashboard1</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="selectDashboard('d2')">Dashboard2</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

scss seems to work - the button is formatted normally, but on click it doesn't work. please help.

Comment: Without even looking at the module I'm just going to guess that bootstrap css is not included (otherwise it would need to reproduce everything inline, so a lot of work I'm sure that has not been done). Therefore you would actually need to import the css to your project. Which I guess you have not done. Past libraries like this just implement the code parts and not the css. So my guess is this is no different.

Comment: no. just added <link href="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> to index.html same thing dropdown doesn't open.

Comment: Well, you're not using the dropdown component of ng-bootstrap, so why should that do anything? Read the documentation. Look at the demos code. https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown

Answer (score 2):

Not sure *how* you expect it to work since you don't seem to be using *any* of the [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io) directives (`ngbDropdown`, `ngbDropdownToggle`). If you check the [official demo site for dropdowns](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown) you will see this simple markup:

```
<div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownToggle>Toggle dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
    <button class="dropdown-item">Action - 1</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item">Another Action</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item">Something else is here</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can even fork a plunker from the demo site and see this code working live: http://plnkr.co/edit/lfsIdlSo5wIkmxP01uaQ?p=preview

To resolve your problem:

- Make sure that you are actually using ng-bootstrap directives as documented at https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown
- Inspect the sample plunker and compare your code with the one here: http://plnkr.co/edit/lfsIdlSo5wIkmxP01uaQ?p=preview[enter link description here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io)

Comment: Im using this documentation https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/dropdowns/ am i doing something wrong?

Comment: You're reading the documentation of Bootstrap's jQuery-based components, but you want to use ng-bootstrap's angular-based components. They look the same, rely on the same bootstrap CSS, but the way to use and manipulate them is not the same.

Comment: how can I use this jquery based component to make dropdown work? It has been imported into project by generator i'm using (https://github.com/angular-starter-kit/generator-ngx-app). I think there is some reason for this

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea at all. If you're using Angular, using Angular components is a way better idea than having to add jQuery to your app and try to make jQuery code fit in Angular's way of doing.

Comment: Hi, Do u know of a way to use the old bootstrap's dropdown-bubble??  the dropdown with a peak?? I needed that. i'm using Angular 4

Answer (score 1):

Seems I've been reading wrong documentation. Thanks to JB Nizet

> You're reading the documentation of Bootstrap's jQuery-based components, but you want to use ng-bootstrap's angular-based components. They look the same, rely on the same bootstrap CSS, but the way to use and manipulate them is not the same. – JB Nizet

dashboard.component.ts should look like this:

```
<div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownToggle>Toggle dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
    <button class="dropdown-item">Action - 1</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item">Another Action</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item">Something else is here</button>
  </div>
</div>
```